# Session variable won't pass to the next page

Tags: php, session, redirect, session-variables

I am passing a variable in the url, example: www.example.com/mypage?gp=32442
Note: This is a WordPress site.

After the gp variable has been saved, I'm comparing it to the current page id and if they are equal i'm setting the cookie and the session and redirecting to the same page only without the "?gp=32442" string at the end.

The cookies are working correctly, but I also added the session variable in case there are people with cookies disabled.

When I test with cookies disabled, the session variable is empty after the redirection. I tested without the redirect and the session variable is correctly added.

What can I do to keep the session variable after the redirect?

```
 session_start();

    if(isset($_GET["gp"])){ 
            $url_post_id = $_GET["gp"];
        }

    $current_id = get_the_ID();

    // $pageURL is the url without the "?gp=32442" at the end

    if($current_id == $url_post_id){                    
        setcookie("gpcid", $url_post_id, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 14));                 
        $_SESSION['gpsid'] = $url_post_id;
        header('Location: '.$pageURL.'');
    }

    if($_COOKIE["gpcid"] == $current_id || $_SESSION['gpsid'] == $current_id  ){
        the_content();
       } else {.......}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sessions to work cookie should be enabled, because the Sessions works through a basic `sessionId` that it's stored also in and with`COOKIE`.

In other words, you can't benefit from using `$_SESSION` if the user has `COOKIE` disabled.

You could learn more form **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)** and **[here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)**

Comment: So I guess there is no other way of passing a variable if cookies are disabled and I don't want to pass it through the url?

Comment: You could you a form with a hidden input element, but if the user inspect page source can see very easy what variable you setted

Comment: Are other ways but depend on what you want to do, you could store you value in database, redirect the client to a url where you set a query string with last insert id, and in the second page you get that the id, search in in db... it's just an example. depend on what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for all the usefull info :)

Comment: Cu placere, Roxana :).